# Java - How to get the state of a process / task (windows)?

Tags: java

I'm making an "application" with friends for my school in JAVA which have to get the state of a process / task running on Windows.
For example, he would have to return a value when "chrome.exe *32" is running on the actual open sessions.

I'm may be wrong but I was thinking of using something like that:

```
if([this is the part I know now what to put here] == true)
{
        return a value
}
```

or may be with the memory taken by the process, I really don't know how to get this value.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try searching around for possible help on Stack Overflow or Google before posting this?  It is unlikely that someone is going to give you the full code you need based on your current question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a process that runs a powershell command and read the resulting information back:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder()
        .command("powershell", "invoke-command", "-computerName", "MYCOMPUTER", "-filepath", ".\\someScript.psl")
        .start();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
p.waitFor();
List<String> results = new LinkedList();
String line;
while ((line == reader.readLine()) != null) results.add(line);
```

`results` now contains all the resulting input from the process you created. Below is the script contained in the `someScript.psl` file:

```
$sched = New-Object -Com "Schedule.Service"
$sched.connect()
$out = @()
$sched.GetFolder("\").GetTasks(0) | % {
    $xml = [xml]$_.xml
    $out += New-Object psobject -Property @{
        "Name" = $_.Name
        "Status" = switch($_.State) {0 {"Unknown"} 1 {"Disabled"} 2 {"Queued"} 3 {"Ready"} $ {"Running"}}
        "NextRunTime" = $_.NextRunTime
        "LastRunTime" = $_.LastRunTime
        "LastRunResult" = $_.LastTaskResult
        "Author" = $xml.Task.Principals.Principal.UserID
        "Created" = $xml.Task.RegistrationInfo.Date
    }
}
$out | fl Name, Status, NextRunTime, LastRunTime, LastRunResult, Author, Created
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get information about a process using java 9's ProcessHandle interface.
To get information about processes just iterate using the following code and use processHandle methods.

```
ProcessHandle.allProcesses().forEach(process -> processStateInfo(process));
```

Below code iterates over all the processes and prints some information about those processes.

```
public class JavaProcess {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProcessHandle.allProcesses().forEach(process -> getProcessInfo(process));
    }

    private static void getProcessInfo(ProcessHandle process) {
        System.out.println("PID == "+process.pid());
        System.out.println("Is ProcessAlive=="+process.isAlive());
        System.out.println("Command=="+process.info().command());
        System.out.println("ProcessStartTime=="+process.info().startInstant());
        System.out.println("Duration=="+process.info().totalCpuDuration());
        System.out.println("Process User=="+process.info().user());
    }

}
```

Note that **isAlive()** method might return true for some time even after the process is requested to terminate. This happens because process is terminated asynchonously.

Here is doc for ProcessHandle Interface.
http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html

Comment: Thanks you for your answer.